# Problem with Sonarqube and error with maven Coverage checks not met. See log for more details

Tags: maven, sonarqube, apache-camel, quarkus, jacoco

Good afternoon

Currently I must pass my code through sonarqube, but I have problems with maven that indicates an error that I do not comply with Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details, however, I can't see exactly in which logs I can see what I'm missing to meet the coverage:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.399 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-09T18:43:28-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:check (jacoco-check) on project find-customer-by-doc-id: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I am using jacoco and validating in the report, I am covering most of the code in the classes:

C:\Users\cesar\Desktop\Trabajo\Ambientes\DEV\Microservicios\find-customer-by-doc-id\target\jacoco-report

index.html

[image]

This is my pom xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.tmve.customer</groupId>
  <artifactId>find-customer-by-doc-id</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.7.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.7</jacoco.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-camel-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-bean</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-direct</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-log</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-openapi-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>4.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-opentelemetry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <excludedGroups>!integration</excludedGroups>
              <groups>integration</groups>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <exclClassLoaders>*QuarkusClassLoader</exclClassLoaders>
              <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</destFile>
              <append>true</append>
              <excludes>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</dataFile>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-report</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-check</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</dataFile>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <element>BUNDLE</element>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>LINE</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>0.5</minimum>
                    </limit>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>0.5</minimum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

My application.properties:

```
#https
quarkus.ssl.native=true
quarkus.http.ssl-port=${PORT:8080}
quarkus.http.read-timeout=${SERVICE_READ_TIMEOUT:20000}
quarkus.http.insecure-requests=disabled
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=${UBICATION_CERTIFICATE_SSL:META-INF/resources/srvdevrma1.jks}
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file-type=JKS
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=${PASSWORD_CERTIFICATE_SSL:xxxxxx}
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-key-alias=${ALIAS_CERTIFICATE_SSL:srvdevrma1}
quarkus.http.cors=true

client.file=${CLIENT-FILE:META-INF/resources/srvdevrma1.jks}
client.password=${CLIENT-PASSWORD:xxxxxx}
quarkus.native.additional-build-args=-H:IncludeResources=.*\\.jks
quarkus.native.resources.includes=*.jks
#GlobalVariables
server.variables.msgType=RESPONSE
server.variables.msgTypeError=ERROR
descripcion.servicio=MicroServicio orquestador encargado de realizar la consulta de detalle de facturas para cuentas postpago..

error.400.code=INVALID_ARGUMENT
error.400.message=Client specified an invalid argument, request body or query param

error.403.code=PERMISSION_DENIED
error.403.message=Authenticated user has no permission to access the requested resource

error.404.code=NOT_FOUND
error.404.message=A specified resource is not found

error.500.code=INTERNAL
error.500.message=Server error

error.503.code=UNAVAILABLE
error.503.message=Service unavailable

error.504.code=TIMEOUT
error.504.message=Request timeout exceeded. Try it later

descripcion.servicio=MicroServicio que permite orquestar la busqueda de informacion asociados a clientes Naturales y Juridicos

#endpoints_ms- local
client.findIndividualCustomerByDocId=${UBICATION-URL-FIND-INDIVIDUAL-CUSTOMER-BY-DOC-ID:https://localhost:8081/api/FindIndividualCustomerByDocId}
client.findOrganizacionCustomerByDocId=${UBICATION-URL-FIND-ORGANIZATION-CUSTOMER-BY-DOC-ID:https://localhost:8082/api/FindOrganizationCustomerByDocId}
#timeZone
quarkus.jackson.timezone=${TIME_ZONE:GMT-4}

#Ruta OpenApi
path.openapi=/users/.*/customers/openapi/swagger-ui/
quarkus.camel.openapi.expose.enabled=true
#camel.rest.api-context-path = /openapi.yaml
#quarkus.swagger-ui.urls.camel = /openapi.yaml
#openapi
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path=/api/FindCustomerByDocId/swagger
#quarkus.swagger-ui.path= /api/FindCustomerByDocId/swagger-ui/
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true

#opentelemetry
quarkus.application.name=FindCustomerByDocId
quarkus.opentelemetry.enabled=true
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint=${URL_JAEGER:http://172.28.2.107:4317}
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p traceId=%X{traceId}, parentId=%X{parentId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
quarkus.http.header."X-Content-Type-Options".value=nosniff
quarkus.http.header."X-Frame-Options".value=DENY
quarkus.http.header."Content-Security-Policy".value=default-src
```

I am currently using Quarkus version 2.16 and Apache Apache Camel 3.20.1, and I am using Rest Assured for unit testing.

I don't understand, since according to the limits of the covergare that I indicate in the pom.xml, I should exceed it according to the jacoco report, that's why I want to know where to see the logs in detail and what I might be missing